# Difference between Google Server and Android API keys for Places

Tags: android, google-maps, google-places-api

I am trying to access Google Places service through an Android app.

I have setup everything as I think it is required. I got the key the as mentioned here [Here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) The documentation just mentioned going to API Access panel over Google code and selecting `Create new Server key.` But I am using it through my Android device so shouldn't I be use the `Create new Android key.` and it is the same key that I am suing for google maps API over my device right?

But when I am suing the key and making API request I am getting this error:

```
This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.
```

What am I doing wrong, am i using the wrong key if yes why shouldnt i be using Android key for an Android device? And if it has to be Server key, than what IP Addresses should i give while generating a server key? please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation clearly says:

> You'll need your own server API key before you can begin using the API

You cannot access this api from your device, you suppose to access it from your server and path the information to your users.